# How to select an option with a tap instead of tapping "done"on iPhone, and call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

New to js. Can't seem to find a good answer to selecting an option in a select input form without clicking the "Done" on iPhone. I just want to click on the option, which will trigger a call to a js function.